# How to set the value for an ng-model within a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat, which I put inside an select tag.
I want to be able to modify the selected values on different selects.
here is what I have :
the html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <select ng-model="nbModel" ng-options="numValue.Text for numValue in numValues" ng-change="chooseUser(nbModel, user.id)">
                        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{user.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{user.age}} years
    </div>
</div>
```

the js

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.numValues = [ {Id : '0',Text : '0'}, {Id : '1',Text : '1'}, {Id : '2',Text : '2' }];    
    $scope.users = [];

    $scope.users.push(new User(1, 'Luke', 23));
    $scope.users.push(new User(2, 'Maria', 26));
    $scope.users.push(new User(3, 'Mike', 45));

    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(equip) {
        //TODO to set the default values for each select
    });

    $scope.chooseUser= function(value, name) {
        //some traitement        
        //TODO to set a wanted value        
    };
};

function User(id, name, age) {
    this.id=id;
    this.firstnamename = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

I could not figure out how to manually set the selected options.
any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're half way there... what you need to do is set ng-model to something on your user you want to change. Presuming you wanted to change the age of the user with the select, it would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <select ng-model="user.age" ng-options="numValue.Text for numValue in numValues"></select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{user.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{user.age}} years
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I see the idea, can the ng-model be dynamic ? i mean something like like ng-model="userModel[user.id]" ? if yes, how would update it from js, $scope.userModel[1] = ... ?

Comment: Yes, ng-model can be dynamic, if you want. [Here's a quick example](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1iNfC5t8lts6z20a6wY?p=preview)